# How can I discard the default branch?

Tags: mercurial

On rev 24, I created a branch for a new feature, meanwhile, other people kept on working on the default (revs 26,28 and 29) but ended up leaving the project in a bad state. I kept developing on the branch (up to rev 36), which should now become the default branch. How do I do that?

I tried going back to 24 on default and merging with 36, and I got a 37 on default just like I wanted. But now it complains about having two heads (37 and 29). I don't want to merge, because 26,28 and 29 are no good. I tried going to 37 and doing hg merge --tool internal:local -r 29 to discard 29, but it didn't work.

This seems to be really simple, but I'm kind of stuck.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "it _complains_ about having 2 heads"? If this is what you want, I don't see any problem about having 2 heads, and neither does `hg`.

Comment: Well, it's case: "One hg glog will tells more than one million words"

Comment: Adding a text diagram of the branch layout will help people trying to answer this question to better understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

One way to resolve this is simply to close the branch that you don't want:

```
hg update 29
hg commit --close-branch -m "closing branch"
```

Technically you would still have two heads, but one would be marked as closed, so you wouldn't notice it in general use (for example if you ran `hg heads`).

Alternatively, I would guess that where you state mercurial "complains about having two heads", it is when you are trying to push to another repository.  In this case you can specify that yes, you do in fact know about the new head and accept that it exists.  If you do this following marking the branch as closed, it should not cause any issues:

```
hg push --force
```

You could, however, get an ambiguity when you do an update, so it's possibly a good idea to specify the revision in that case.

Finally, if you don't want to see the changesets that you've not merged into your own branch, you could specify your own latest revision when cloning to a new repository:

```
hg clone project new_project --rev 37
```

I *think* that this would create a clone of just the changesets needed to get to that revision.  You could then use this as the basis for your work.  The downside is that you would not have non-ancestor changesets that you may actually want.

For other options, I would look into some of the extensions packaged with Mercurial, such as `strip`. I have not used this, so can't give you any advice on it.

You can look [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PruningDeadBranches) for more information.

Comment: `push --create-branch` wrong, because OP have anonymos branching case and 2 heads in (default) branch, not new one-head branch

Comment: +1 for including a link to the Pruning Dead Branches wiki page, which is the correct reference for this type of issue.  The answer might be a bit better if you made that reference more prominant, though.

Answer (score 1):

Claudio, I'll try to "translate" your question into more clean form (check translation and fixme, if needed)

You created *anonymous branch* in named `default` branch at rev 24, now you want to use only some changesets from another tree in your development and have problems on push to remote server with complaint about creating additional head.

Is my reconstruction correct?

If "yes" and unwanted changesets 26,28,29 are in single continuous range you can merge at "last good" foreign changeset (merging 24 is useless, AFAICS without glog - it seems as branchpoint) and close unwanted head: @icabod was correct with --close-branch recipe

From other side, if your repository is unique and wasn't published, you can rewrite history (MQ: strip, histedit...) and before merging delete bad changesets, get clean second anonymous branch, merge, commit, push

You can also (while it's not recommended) `push -f`, and have both heads pushed to remote repo, you head will be active, while you and others work with it

**Fix for cleared by comments pic**

Corrected reconstruction, iteration 2: You have in default branch some changesets, which changes you want to exclude from mainline and merge your branch to default.

Except suggested earlier history rewriting (the whole kill of changesets from history - applicable for "unpublished" repository) you can leave bad changesets in history, but undo their changes for the cost of additional changesets: `hg backout -r REV` create changeset, undoing of changes from REV (can't recall about using revrange here). Three (max)  new backout-changesets in default and you are ready to merge your branch to default (you can backout even after merge).

Comment: Hi,Your reconstruct is nearly correct. The only different is that it is a named branch, not an anonymous one.
Is it still ok to do the close? 

ps: thanks for the "translation"

Comment: @ClaudioCoelho - "named branch with two heads" IS *anonymous branching*, as Steve Losh used this term, and it's conventional term. Yes, it's OK to use --close-branch for any heads in any branches

Comment: I can close the default branch (at 29), and it works. But then I have to use another name for the default branch. I would like to discard the revisions 26,28 and 29, and have what I have in the named branch be on the default branch. Is it possible?

Comment: @ClaudioCoelho - ok, now I see. My reconstruction was wrong on 90%. See my edits in answer

Comment: Thanks :) for the feedback. I ended up using strip

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to (a) restore `default` to the state it had at revision 24 (without destroying any history), then (b) merge your feature branch back onto default. You complicated things a bit by creating two heads in default, but no biggie. Let's take it one step at a time.

(I recommend cloning your entire repo so that you can experiment in peace. If you do something you don't like, just remove the entire directory and start over).

Here's how to reverse the effect of the misguided changes (without using commands like `strip` that destructively rewrite history):

1. Update to the head of default:

   ```
   hg update -r 29
   ```
2. Without changing the "current" revision, switch all files to what they were at revision 24:

   ```
   hg revert -r 24
   ```
3. Commit this file state as the new head of `default`:

   ```
   hg commit -m "Backing out revisions 26,28,29"
   ```

At this point, you could have just merged your feature branch onto the new head of `default`, since all the wrong changes have been backed out:

```
    hg merge feature
```

This should be the end of the story. But you've already merged `feature` into rev 24, getting revset 37. No problem, you can still do steps 1-3, which will give you a default head with none of the destructive changes. Then, instead of merging the head of `feature`, merge `37` as the last step:

```
    hg merge -r 37
```

This will unify the heads of `default`, without any adverse effects since you've already backed out the misguided changes.